# Jasmine object “has no method 'andReturn'”

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, tdd, jasmine

Beginner with Jasmine, very first attempt with Jasmine Spies.  I thought I was mimicking the format [displayed here](http://pivotal.github.io/jasmine/) (search: "andReturn"), but I'm getting an error that I can't work out:

```
TypeError: Object function () {
        callTracker.track({
          object: this,
          args: Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments)
        });
        return spyStrategy.exec.apply(this, arguments);
      } has no method 'andReturn'
```

No clue what I'm doing wrong.  Here's my Spec:

```
describe('Die', function() {
    it('returns a value when you roll it', function() {
        var die = Object.create(Die);
        spyOn(Math, 'random').andReturn(1);
        expect(die.roll()).toEqual(6);
    });
});
```

And the corresponding JS:

```
var Die = 
{   
    roll: function() {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * 5 + 1);
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help!!!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

jasmine 2.0 changed some of the spy syntax. [jasmine 2.0 docs](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html)

```
spyOn(Math, 'random').and.returnValue(1);
```

Comment: `By chaining the spy with and.returnValue, all calls to the function will return a specific value.`

Comment: Yes!  Looks like andReturn is now and.returnValue.

Comment: Would have been better to provide the code in the answer, rather than *just* link to the docs.

Answer (score 11):

try this

> spyOn(Math, 'random').and.returnValue(1);

Comment: This is the current 2.0.0 jasmine syntax

Answer (score 2):

I made a jasmine test where I show this kind of mock. andReturn seems to be working. http://jsfiddle.net/LNWXn/

```
it("has a value of 1 with and return", function() {
    spyOn(Math, 'random').andReturn(1); 
    expect(Math.random()).toBe(1);
});
```

You have to keep in mind that it's only mocked for the scope of the test. 
Here's one with your example that seems to pass. http://jsfiddle.net/LNWXn/2/

Hope this helped!

Comment: Thanks!  I actually think that the problem might have something to do with the fact that I was using dist 2.0.  I recreated the exact tests in 1.3.1 and they worked just fine.

Answer (score 1):

use and.returnValue() insted of andReturn()