# Mocking a Service into Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to mock a service, with Jasmine 2.2.0: `CheckoutService.patch()` which returns a promise into my `CheckoutController`:

```
describe('CheckoutController', function() {
    var $scope, vm, checkoutServiceMock, def;

    beforeEach(function(){
        module('app');

        checkoutServiceMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('CheckoutService', ['patch']);

        inject(function($rootScope, $controller, $q){
            def = $q.defer();

            $scope = $rootScope.$new();

            vm = $controller('CheckoutController', {
                $scope: $scope,
                CheckoutService: checkoutServiceMock
            });

            checkoutServiceMock.patch.andReturn(def.promise);
        });
   });
});
```

But I'm getting: `TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'checkoutServiceMock.patch.andReturn(def.promise)')`

What I am missing?

Comment: Probably this is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21590005/jasmine-object-has-no-method-andreturn, i.e. the syntax does not match your version of jasmine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that you should change `andReturn` to `and.callfake()`, for example:

```
spyOn(checkoutServiceMock, "patch").and.callFake(function() {
  return def.promise;
});
```

See [docs](http://jasmine.github.io/2.2/introduction.html#section-Spies:_<code>and.callFake</code>) for Jasmine 2.2.